# cgi pages not working from local IIS

Tags: perl, iis, iis-7.5

I recently had my computer reimaged and reinstalled everything. Everything works except that from my localhost, if i browse a cgi page it throws

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error The page cannot be displayed
>   because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> Module CgiModule
>
> Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler Perl script
>
> Error Code 0x800700c1
>
> Requested URL localhost:80/website1/index.cgi
>
> Logon Method NTLM

I have Windows authentication enabled and everything else disabled. My ISAPI and CGI restriction shows everything is allowed. My Handler Mappings (at machine level) has *.cgi enabled with CGIModule (which runs \inetsrv\cgi.dll which exists). I dont know what else to check. Please advise.

Any idea how to correct/debug this? I have IIS 7.5 on windows 7.

Comment: I guess permission issue or cgi not enabled.

Comment: Doesn't the IIS log show some more information as to why this fails? "Everything works except that from my localhost" Does this work if you browse via another machine?

Comment: I checked the IIS logs and eventvwr. Nothing. Browsing via another machine also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is what i did

- Uninstall Perl if you have it installed already. (We will reinstall after we install IIS). Delete c:Perl if you have. Importantly, make a copy before you do.
- Uninstall IIS if you have it installed already. (We will reinstall). Delete c:inetpub and c:\Windows\system32inetsrv. Make a copy before you do, just in case.
- After uninstalling through control panel, execute the following uninstall command also for clean uninstall

  start /w pkgmgr /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
- Restart the machine
- Install IIS. Make sure to install CGI part in IIS before installing perl
- Check if everything in IIS (other than CGI) works. You may have to register aspnet after IIS install.

  %windir%Microsoft.NETFramework64v4.0.30319aspnet_regiis.exe -i
- Install Perl. When clicking Next, you should see a screen for 'Choose Setup Options' and have options like a) Add perl to the PATH environment variable b) Create .plx script mapping for perl ISAPI, c) create .pl script mapping for PERL etc. Check all of those options
- Compare your backed up perl location and the new location (C:\Perl). Copy any missing files
- Create application pool and virtual directory in IIS. In application pool, "Enable 32 bit application"
- Add ISAPI and CGI restrictions in IIS. Do the following from command prompt.

  c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config /section:isapiCgiRestriction /+"[path='C:perlbinperl.exe "%s %s"',description='Perl',allowed='True']"